# Lists inside classes?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, list

I have a List of strings called `Names` in a class called `data`. The code for the list looks like this:

```
public class data {
  public List<string> Names = new List<string>();
  Names.Add("C1");
}
```

When I run the program, the code fails on the line with `names.Add("C1");`

[edit] The error message given is "*The type or namespace Names could not be found (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*"

Comment: What does it yell at you ? Also, show some surrounding code, or the class - it will help us.

Comment: When it yells at you, what does it say?

Comment: What error are you getting specifically? It's hard to tell what the issue is when we can't see the error message or enough code to determine the issue.

Comment: im editing the question for surrounding code now...

Comment: Your code looks fine, so the problem involves the context. Show more code, please.

Comment: I added the extra code and error describtion into the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to take a shot in the dark and guess your class looks like this:

```
public class data
{
    public List<string> Names = new List<string>();
    Names.add("C1");
}
```

In this case the problem is infact the add method is not a member or method declaration and cannot exist where it is. One solution would be to add that in the constructor:

```
public class data
{
    public List<string> Names = new List<string>();

    public data()
    {
        Names.Add("C1");
    }
}
```

Another option is to add it to the declaration:

```
public List<string> Names = new List<string>(){ "C1" };
```

Comment: Sorry, i should've included the entire code, i updated the question with the new code

Comment: based on what you provided this is infact the issue. You cannot do Names.Add() in the class declaration. Also you are missing a ';' on the `public static string ID = "n"` line.

Comment: I initialized the C1 in the declaration like you said which worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your class looks like this

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<string> Names = new List<string>();
    Names.Add("C1");
}
```

then that is indeed illegal. The class level is for defining members, and is not for calling methods (the `Add` statement). You instead need to call the `Add` method inside a method or constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<string> Names = new List<string>();

    public MyClass()
    {
        Names.Add("C1");
    }
}
```

or alternatively, simply initialize the list with that value:

```
public List<string> Names = new List<string>() { "C1" };
```